# Array Formula with 3 IF statements?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using google sheets, and trying to look up the string value in cell A4, check column A of Sheet2 for a matching string, then (once found) return the soonest date in column C where;
Column A matches A4
Column I = TRUE
Column J = blank

The formula I've come up with is this;

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF((Sheet2!A:A=A5)(Sheet2!I:I=TRUE)(Sheet2!J:J=""),Sheet2!C:C,"")))
```

which returns the error

> invalid call to non-function

My previous formula;

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF((Sheet2!A:A=A4)*(Sheet2!I:I=TRUE),Sheet2!C:C,"")))
```

Was returning a date, but I needed to add the additional IF statement to check column J is blank, and that's where I think I'm failing - but I'm not entirely sure why. I've tried

Sheet here with example, feel free to edit;
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kUQ2Ut59VZtKGWwyNCwAilIEWHWSk45HP0u1qMORsRA/edit?usp=sharing

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Google Sheets and Excel are two separate products, and are not entirely compatible. If you're using Google Sheets, the Excel tag is not applicable. I've removed it for that reason. Tag-spamming (using tags that do not apply to your post) is highly discouraged here, and is a quick way to get your posts downvoted and/or closed. Tags have relevance and meaning, and should be used properly.

Comment: Ah, sure thing will bear that in mind for future. Thanks for letting me know, & apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=sortn(filter(Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!A:A=A4,Sheet2!I:I=TRUE,Sheet2!J:J=""),1,,1,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the asterisks in like you did with your original formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF((Sheet2!A:A=A5)*(Sheet2!I:I=TRUE) * (Sheet2!J:J=""),Sheet2!C:C,"")))
```

But also check the locale settings of your sheet because the dates appear to be in DD/MM/YYYY format while the locale is set to US (MM/DD/YYYY).

Or you could try using a query:

```
=query({Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet2!C2:C,Sheet2!I2:I,Sheet2!J2:J},"select Col1,min(Col2) where Col3=true and Col4 is null group by Col1")
```

[image]